# Why x[False] and x[True] for python list work?

Tags: python, list, boolean

If I have `x` as the list of items, why does the `x[True]` or `x[False]` modifies the first or second elements of the list?

Please see code sample below:

```
x = [1, 2]
x[True] = 'a'
x[False] = 'b'
print(x) # --> ['a', 'b']
```

Please give explanation why this code works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since x is the `list` the passed index is being converted to the integer representation. The integer representation of the True and False are 1 and 0 respectively. As result it leads to the modification of the first and second elements in the list. From the [Python Data model documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy):

> These represent the truth values False and True. The two objects
>   representing the values False and True are the only Boolean objects.
>   The Boolean type is a subtype of the integer type, and Boolean values
>   behave like the values 0 and 1, respectively, in almost all contexts,
>   the exception being that when converted to a string, the strings
>   "False" or "True" are returned, respectively.

In addition to the sample with the list that causes interesting behaviour for the dictionary:

```
x = {}
x[True] = 'a'
print(x) # --> {True: 'a'}
x[1] = 'b' 
print(x) # --> {True: 'b'} and not {True: 'a', 1: 'b'}
```

Comment: Please consider moving your answer to the duplicate question. It's a good answer, and it should be listed there with the others.

Comment: can we flag the answer so a mod moves it keeping the score ? is it just possible?